# Equality of sums with fractional parts of the form $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\{\frac{mk}{n}\}$

Tags: number-theory, summation, fractional-part

I recently encountered the following equality ($\{\}$ denotes fractional part):

$$\sum_{k=1}^{65}k\left\{\frac{8k}{65}\right\}=\sum_{k=1}^{65}k\left\{\frac{18k}{65}\right\}$$

and found it very interesting as most of the individual summands on one side of the equation do not have a corresponding match on the other side. Investigating further, I found several other similar equalities:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{77}k\left\{\frac{9k}{77}\right\}=\sum_{k=1}^{77}k\left\{\frac{16k}{77}\right\}$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{77}k\left\{\frac{17k}{77}\right\}=\sum_{k=1}^{77}k\left\{\frac{24k}{77}\right\}$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{85}k\left\{\frac{7k}{85}\right\}=\sum_{k=1}^{85}k\left\{\frac{22k}{85}\right\}$$

Does anyone have any idea what general principle/pattern these arise from?

Comment: It may help to rewrite it like this:
$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\{\frac{ak}{n}\} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}k\frac{ak \mod n}{n}$

Comment: @MichaelStocker And then you can remove the division, since it just scales the values...

Comment: What does it look like when you write it in terms of Dedekind sums?

Comment: It's interesting that, in the examples I've run (still relatively small) there are always $1,2,$ or $4$ numerators that yield the same value, but never $3$ or more than $4$. I've only been checking denominators that are a product of two primes.

Comment: When the denominator is divisible by $3$ distinct primes primes, you can find $6$ and $8$ numerators that yield the same value, but still no examples of a value reached by exactly an odd number of numerators, other than $1$...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Makes sense, as modular inverses over the denominator will always be equal.

Comment: By the way, you really only need the upper bound $k=n-1$ - $k=n$ contributes zero always...

Comment: Is that obvious, @ruadan - that if $ab\equiv 1\pmod n$ then the sum above for numerator $a$ and numerator $b$ are the same? It seems like something to mention in your question, if you have that result and are looking for different results...

Comment: In all of these cases $(a-b)(ab-1)$ is divisible by $n$...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews there are numbers that are their own multiplicative inverse $\pmod{n}$. I think those are candidates for a odd quantity of numerators that yield the same value.

Comment: Isn't $\sum k\{a_1k/c\}=\sum k\{a_2k/c\}$ the same as $s(a_1,c)=s(a_2,c)$, where $s(a,c)$ is the Dedekind sum?

Comment: It's not *obviously* true, @GerryMyerson, since the change from the fractional part to the rounding part affects the terms inconsistently.

Answer (score 2):

Given $n$, let $a$ and $b$ be integers coprime with $n$. Then:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k \left\{ \frac{ak}{n}\right\} = \sum_{k=1}^n k \left\{ \frac{bk}{n}\right\}$$

As Michael Stocker commented:

$$f(a,n) = \sum_{k=1}^n k \left\{ \frac{ak}{n}\right\} = \sum_{k=1}^n k  \frac{ak \mod n}{n} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n k  (ak \mod n)$$
$$f(b,n) = \sum_{k=1}^n k \left\{ \frac{bk}{n}\right\} = \sum_{k=1}^n k  \frac{bk \mod n}{n} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n k  (bk \mod n)$$

I've been able to prove that, as Thomas Andrews said, if $ab \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ then $f(a,n) = f(b,n)$:

Let $k' := ak \mod n$ then $k' (bk' \mod n) = k (ak \mod n)$. Here's the proof:
$k'[b(ak \mod n) \mod n] = k'(abk \mod n) = k'(k \mod n) = k'k = k(ak \mod n)$.

Note that $\lbrace (ak \mod n) \vert 1\leq k \leq n\rbrace = \lbrace 0, 1,2\cdots ,n-1\rbrace$.

So now $$f(a,n) = \sum_{k=1}^n k \left\{ \frac{ak}{n}\right\} = \sum_{k'=1}^n k' \left\{ \frac{bk'}{n}\right\} = f(b,n)$$

Now for the cases like $f(8,65) = f(18,65)$ where $ab \not\equiv 1$ I've found that $$k(ak \mod n) - k(bk\mod n) = \\(n-k)(b(n-k)\mod n) - (n-k)(b(n-k)\mod n)$$

But so far I've been unable to caracterize the pairs $(a,b)$ with that property.

Comment: But doesn't the first sum become $\sum_{k=1}^n k \left\{ \frac{bk'}{n}\right\}$ instead of $\sum_{k=1}^n k \left\{ \frac{bk}{n}\right\}$?

Comment: @N.S. It will become $\sum_{k'=1}^n k' \left\{\frac{bk'}{n}\right\}$ wich is equivalent... I think

Comment: No it doesn't. As you said, for each $k$ there exists a $k'$ so that $\left\{ \frac{ak}{n} \right\}= \left\{ \frac{bk'}{n} \right\}$. Which means that $k\left\{ \frac{ak}{n} \right\}$ becomes  $k\left\{ \frac{bk'}{n} \right\}$....

Comment: @N.S. You are absolutely right. I'll try to think a way to fix this.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews my proof is not right as pointed out in the comment. I'm trying to work out a fix. I think $a$ and $b$ must me coprime with $n$ but $a-b$ must not.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think I've proved that $ab \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ is sufficient (although as we've seen, not necessary). Read after the stricken lines. =D

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small GNU Maxima script to ease experimentation

---

```
    display2d : false;

    /* x rational */
    my_floor(x) := block(
        if (x >= 0) then block(
            ab : divide(ratnumer(x),ratdenom(x)),
            a : ab[1], b : ab[2],
            if (b = 0) then block(
                return(x)
            ) else block(
                return(x - b/ratdenom(x))
            )
        ) else block(
            ab : divide(ratnumer(-x),ratdenom(-x)),
            a : ab[1], b : ab[2],
            if (b = 0) then block(
                return(x)
            ) else block(
                return(x - (1-b/ratdenom(-x)))
            )
        )
    );

    /* x rational */
    my_frac(x) := x - my_floor(x);

    cz : 0; cnz : 0;
    for N : 1 thru 20 do block(
    for m1 : 1 thru 20 do block(
    for m2 : m1+1 thru 20 do block(
        mylhs : apply("+",makelist(k*my_frac(m1*k/N),k,1,N)),
        myrhs : apply("+",makelist(k*my_frac(m2*k/N),k,1,N)),
        if (mylhs - myrhs = 0) then block(
            cz : cz+1,
            print(N,m1,m2,"|",mylhs)
        ) else block(
            cnz : cnz+1
        )
    )));
    print(cz,"|",cnz);
```

---

Comment: Using the script above, I have found no solutions with $1 \le N,m1,m2 \le 100$, $gcd(N,m1) \neq 1$, $gcd(N,m2) \neq 1$, $gcd(m1,m2) = 1$.

Comment: What do you mean by "no solutions?" Do you mean no more solutions than the ones above?

Comment: Exactly what I've said. I have found no solution for $1 \le N,m1,m2 \le 100$ with the additional conditions $gcd(N,m1) \neq 1$, $gcd(N,m2) \neq 1$ and $gcd(m1,m2) = 1$. You may substitute $m1=a$ and $m2=b$.

Comment: Sorry, reading comprehension failure on my part - read $\neq$ as $=$...

Comment: Because of my low reputation, I comment here. I believe we should identify the pattern of the function $f(n,m,k) := (n-m)/n - \{mk/N\} + \{m(k+1)/N\}$ in order to perform a summation by parts.

Comment: typo: should have written $f(N,m,k):= (N-m)/N - \{mk/N\} + \{m(k+1)/N\}$

Answer (score 0):

[Raw data deleted.]

Defining $$f(a,n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k\left\{\frac{ka}{n}\right\}$$ it's pretty obvious that $f(a,n)+f(n-a,n)=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ when $(a,n)=1$. It's also true, as proven by Darth Geek, that if $ab\equiv 1\pmod n$ then $f(a,n)=f(b,n)$.

Further data leads to:

> **Conjecture:** If $f(a,n)=f(b,n)$ then $n\mid (a-b)(ab-1)$, or, equivalently, $a+a^{-1}\equiv b+b^{-1}\pmod n$, where the inverses are taken modulo $n$.

This would mean that the pairs $a,a^{-1}$ are the only solutions when $n$ a prime.

It is definitely not sufficient, since $a=3,b=48,n=65$ satisfies this condition.

This conjecture holds for all integers $4\leq n\leq 5000$.

$$\begin{align}f(a,n)&=\frac{a}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^2 - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k\left\lfloor\frac{ka}{n}\right\rfloor\\
&=\frac{a(n-1)(2n-1)}{6} - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k\left\lfloor\frac{ka}{n}\right\rfloor
\end{align}$$

Thus $f(a,n)$ is an integer if $(n,6)=1$.

Comment: Perhaps the condition is sufficient for prime $n$? It's just a guess since for prime $n$ the sum may behave nicer.

Comment: For prime $n$, that means $ab=1$ or $a=b$, and that does appear to be sufficient in that case, with the data I'm looking at. @barto

Comment: Thank you, that's interesting. Understanding the behavior for prime $n$ would be a good step forward.